# need to get info from mysql with query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `x` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `y` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `z` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=12 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

with this data:

```
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (1, '1', 'A', 'A');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (2, '1', 'B', 'B');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (3, '1', 'A', 'B');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (4, '2', 'A', 'A');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (5, '2', 'A', 'A');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (6, '2', 'A', 'A');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (7, '3', 'B', 'A');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (8, '4', 'B', 'B');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (9, '5', 'C', 'C');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (10, '5', 'C', 'C');
INSERT INTO test(id, x, y, z) VALUES (11, '5', 'A', 'B');
```

im looking about what must be the query in order to get this result:

```
x y/z count    
1 y A 2
1 y B 1
1 z A 1
1 z B 2    
2 y A 3
2 z A 3   
3 y B 1 
3 z A 1   
4 y B 1
4 z B 1    
5 y C 2
5 y A 1
5 z C 2
5 z B 1
```

i have tried with lot of combinations with group by, distinct but i'm unable to get the desired result.

Comment: the inserts sentences was exported by MySQL Workbench as is... i do not do that.

Comment: Wouldn't it be _much_ easier to do 2 separate selects? One for y and one for z? You even could put them together with UNION and then sort ...

Comment: i need to have the info in one view. and really the format i'm looking for is to not have 4 lines for each x. the goal is have one line starting with x and the rest of info in the same line. That is one line for each X

Comment: Ah, whole different story ...

Comment: What is the logic for your desired result?

Comment: i need to know how many times i have a different content for y and z columns (and what is the content) for each x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a `union all` and `group by`:

```
select x, which, val, count(*) as cnt
from ((select x, 'y' as which, y as val from test) union all
      (select x, 'z' as which, z as val from test) 
     ) xyz
group by x, which, val;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a4928/4) is a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: thanks very much for your help. but doesn't work. shows in the cnt column allways value 1

Comment: @PedroTeruelTeodoro . . . I misunderstood the question the first time around.  I fixed the logic.

Answer (score 0):

Here give this a try.  It will create a table for you with two fields that has one row for every x value.  The first field is the x value and the second is a comma separated string of the y/z combinations and their counts.  Does that work for you?

```
select x, y+','+z combo, count(*) cnt into #A from     
   test  
   group by x , y+','+z    

   select x, combo+','+cast(a.cnt as varchar) data into #B  from #A a 

   Select distinct t2.x, 
               substring((Select ', '+t1.data 
                From #b t1
                Where T1.x= T2.x
                ORDER BY T1.x
                For XML PATH ('')),2, 1000) data
         From #b T2
```

Comment: Use your full qualified table name: `3towersdev`.test

Comment: Also this works in sql server.  If you are in mySQL just adjust the last piece of code to utilize a groupconcat